# jsPDF how to rotate a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to create a PDF with javascript and I am stuck at one point where I have to rotate a rectangle.

I have defined my rectangle like this:

```
doc.setFillColor(255,255,200);
doc.rect(100, 0, 70, 70, 'F');
```

In the documentation I found under section `context2d` the `rotate` method which accepts one parameter which is the angle but that is all. I don't know how to use it or if this can be applied to the rectangle.

Comment: How can you define a triangle ? Can you define all 3 angles of the triangle ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I end up using 2 triangles because it suited my needs more than the rotated rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with something like this with context2d:

```
context = doc.context2d;
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(545, 205, 50, 40);
context.rotate(Math.PI/4)
context.rect(5, 5, 150, 150);
context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

or use `lines` or `path` and draw it manually.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful for me. Meanwhile I discovered the triangle thanks to K J so I used that instead because I needed a sharp angle in my scenario and the rectangle forced me to had a 90 degree angle. But your answer was good for my question so I marked it as good.